# Why use single quote around vector in "use" (in clojure)?

Tags: clojure

When I use some long function names, I used the `use` form, like this:

```
(use '[clojure.string :as str])
```

But I don't know why add a *single quote* `'` to the vector, so I tried to figure out its type:

```
(type '[clojure.string :as str])
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

Simplified example:

```
(type ["hello"])
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentVector

(type '["hello"])
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

It seems the *single quote* doesn't change anything, can anybody explain the usage of it in the `use` form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The intent is to quote the *symbols*. This way they'll be treated as symbols, and `use` can take those symbols as naming a namespace to load and pull into the current. You want to avoid the default treatment of a symbol, which is resolving it as the name of a Var and using the value of that Var. You can also do this as

```
(use ['clojure.string :as 'str])
```

but that involves some unnecessary typing; quoting the whole vector makes you less likely to forget anything. Particularly if you're doing anything with `:only`, `:refer` or similar keyword arguments.

Aside: `ns` doesn't need this because as a macro it can control evaluation of its arguments - functions like `require` and `use` have all their arguments read and evaluated before they themselves run. This is part of the reason why `ns` is normally preferred over those functions.

Answer (score 4):

`use` is a function, hence the evaluator evaluates its arguments before they are passed (applicative order evaluation).

You don't want `[clojure.string :as str]` to be evaluated as the evaluator would try to resolve the symbols in it with no success before applying `use`.

Hence `quote` (reader shorthand `'`) is there to prevent their evaluation.